# How do I retrieve files deleted from local repo using git pull

Tags: git, heroku

While pushing my repo to Heroku I ran a git pull command and it accidentally deleted my local repo. I understand that these files are just stored as objects in .git but whenever I run

```
git checkout .
```

I get this error

```
error: unable to read sha1 file of <file_name> (7caddd272623f5c80b13bcc584418d803e318a19)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Deleting the repository wrecks it; you'll need to clone a fresh one. (The latest Git release has a "repair" mode for `git fetch`, so if you can install Git 2.36 you can use that instead, but it won't really make much difference here.)

Comment: The title says "files deleted from local repo" but the question says "`git pull` accidentally deleted my local repo". I assume the title is correct and the local repo was not deleted?